# Angular: handling component add to form event

Tags: angular, forms, ngx-formly

I'm using formly to get form from json sent by back. Consider the following form description

```
{
    "key": "key_radio",
    "type": "radio",
    "templateOptions": {
        "required": true,
        "options": [
            {
            "value": true,
            "label": "Yes"
            },
            {
            "value": false,
            "label": "No"
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "fieldGroupClassName": "row",
    "hideExpression": "!model.key_radio",
    "fieldGroup": [
        {
            "key": "key_a",
            "className": "col-3",
            "type": "input",
        },
        {
            "key": "key_b",
            "className": "col-4",
            "type": "input"
        },
        {
            "key": "key_c",
            "className": "col-4",
            "type": "input"
        }
    ]
}
```

By default inputs are hidden with `hiddenExpression`. After "Yes" radio-button is clicked inputs are shown. When a value is entered in first input (key_a) I need to do request to backend and fill two other inputs. Listening `form.get('key_a').valueChanges` is a natural solution here. Still I don't know where can I setup this subscription. So the question is: how can I handle inputs add after "Yes" radio-button click and `hideExpression` evaluate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone be reading this, I've found the answer.

One can pass a `fieldChanges` `Subject` and subscribe to it. Formly emits `FormlyValueChangeEvent` in this subject when `hideExpression` is evaluated. With that said, all you need is to subscribe to that `Subject` and do `form.updateValueAndValidity()` in the subscription